# How to exclude multiple domains using W3C's Checklink

Tags: regex, w3c-validation

The `checklink` command supports an --exclude parameter, which accepts a regex. Example:

```
checklink --exclude foo\.com/.* http://example.com
```

Alas, example.com links to multiple sites, many of which use robots.txt to block checklink, and thus I get many link-not-checked messages in the output.

I've excluded foo.com as above. How can I exclude multiple domains? If I have multiple --exclude parameters, only the last one is honoured.

`checklink --version` gives "W3C Link Checker version 4.81 (c) 1999-2011 W3C"; `aptitude show w3c-linkchecker` gives "version 4.81-9"; I'm on Debian Stable.

Answer (score 1):

Hooray for rubber-duck debugging.

The answer is in the regex. Specifically:

```
checklink --exclude "(foo|bar)\.com/.*" http://example.com
```

This excludes all pages on foo.com and on bar.com. Note the quotemarks, the brackets, and the pipe.

The alternatives can also be nested:

```
checklink --exclude "(foo|b(ar|az))\.com/.*" http://example.com
```

This excludes all pages on foo.com, bar.com and on baz.com.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude current *Code: (N/A) Forbidden by robots.txt*

```
checklink --exclude "(facebook.com|linkedin.com|t.co)/.*" http://example.com
```